# Why use an adverb in "an arbitrarily large number"

Tags: grammar, verbs, adverbs, adverbial-phrases

Why use "arbitrary" as an adverb in the following expression:

> an arbitrarily large number

taken from [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arbitrarily).

Where is the verb?

Comment: That is not a sentence.  A sentence needs to have at least a subject and a verb.  Therefore, this is not a sentence.

Comment: @stangdon I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no verb.

The adverb "arbitrarily" is modifying the adjective "large".

[Adverbs can modify verbs, but they can also modify adjectives, determiners, or other adverbs.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverb-phrases?q=adverb)

> an extremely busy person